# Bounding the difference in Expectations over equivalent martingale measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Lets says that we have two processes defined by the following stochastic differential equations.
$$dS_t = \mu (t,\omega)dt + \sigma(t,\omega)dB_t$$ and $$ dR_t = a (t,\omega)dt + b(t,\omega)dB_t$$

And let's assume that I can bound the difference in the expectations of some convex function $f$ at time $T$. This is to say there exists some scalar $C$ such that
$$\big|\mathbb{E}[f(S_T)] - \mathbb{E}[f(R_T)] \big| \le C$$

**What I am trying to do now is, based on this $C$, derive a bound for the following.**
$$\big|\mathbb{E}_W[f(S_T)] - \mathbb{E}_V[f(R_T)] \big|$$

Where $W$ and $V$ are the equivalent martingale measures corresponding to $S_T$ and $R_T$ respectively.

My steps so far:

I start with the later expression, and based on Girsanov theory, we can make a change of measure in the expectation via two martingales: $M_T$ and $N_T$, which are in fact Radon-Nikodym derivatives for $S_T$ and $R_T$ respectively with respect to the natural Brownian filtration. To illustrate better,
$$M_t=\exp\left( -\int_0^T \frac{\mu (t,\omega)}{\sigma (t,\omega)} dB_t - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^T \left( \frac{\mu (t,\omega)}{\sigma (t,\omega)} \right)^2 dt \right)$$
$$N_t=\exp\left( -\int_0^T \frac{a (t,\omega)}{b (t,\omega)} dB_t - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^T \left(\frac{a (t,\omega)}{b (t,\omega)} \right)^2 dt \right)$$

Using these we can re-write that expression with the change of measure, reverting back to the natural filtration.

$$\big|\mathbb{E}_W[f(S_T)] - \mathbb{E}_V[f(R_T)] \big| = \big|\mathbb{E}[M_Tf(S_T)] - \mathbb{E}[N_Tf(R_T)] \big|$$

This is looking promising. However I have been working on it for a few days and I can't seem to get it any farther. The goal is to try to isolate $\big|\mathbb{E}[f(S_T)] - \mathbb{E}[f(R_T)] \big|$ for which we can introduce the constant $C$.

I've tried some straight calculations but now I am starting to think that it may be better to focus on some relationship between $|\mathbb{E}[M_Tf(S_T)] - \mathbb{E}[f(S_T)]|$: is this bounded? We have the property that $M_T$ is a martingale under the natural filtration, so that could be something.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**

$$\bigg|\mathbb{E}_W[ f(S_T)]  - \mathbb{E}_V[ f(R_T) ]\bigg| = \bigg|\mathbb{E}[ f(S_T)M_T]  - \mathbb{E}[ f(R_T)N_T ]\bigg|$$
$$=\bigg|\mathbb{E}[ f(S_T)M_T]  - \mathbb{E}[ f(R_T)N_T ] + \mathbb{E}[ f(S_T)]  - \mathbb{E}[ f(R_T) ] - \mathbb{E}[ f(S_T)]  + \mathbb{E}[ f(R_T) ]\bigg|$$
triangle inequality
$$\le \bigg|\mathbb{E}[ f(S_T)M_T]- \mathbb{E}[ f(S_T)]  - \mathbb{E}[ f(R_T)N_T ] + \mathbb{E}[ f(R_T) ]\bigg| + \bigg|\mathbb{E}[ f(S_T)]  - \mathbb{E}[ f(R_T) ] \bigg|$$
$$\le\bigg|\mathbb{E}[ f(S_T)(M_T-1)] - \mathbb{E}[ f(R_T)(N_T-1) ] \bigg| + C$$

Now I feel like $\mathbb{E}[ f(S_T)(M_T-1)]$ is very small. $M_T$ is a martingale and I think the initial value is 1, so the expected value of $M_T-1$ alone is zero. More importantly we notice that if $S_T = R_T$ then $M_T = N_T$ and $\big|\mathbb{E}[ f(S_T)(M_T-1)] - \mathbb{E}[ f(R_T)(N_T-1) ] \big| = 0$. The point is, as $S_T$ and $R_T$ get closer, this value gets smaller, and I propose it is much smaller than $C$, but I just don't know how to show it.

Comment: How are $W$ and $V$ defined? What is their relation to $M$ and $N$?

Comment: @Sayantan $W$ and $V$ are martingale measures (zero mean) that are defined via $M$ and $N$. According to Girsanov theory $M_t$ and $N_t$ are Radon-Nikodym derivatives. Let's say the base measure with respect to the natural Brownian is $P$, then $dW = M_t dP$ and $dV = N_t dP$. In my math there I use this rule like this: $\mathbb{E}_W[f(S_T)] = \int f(S_T) dW = \int f(S_T) M_T dP = \mathbb{E}[f(S_T) M_T]$. Thanks for the interest!